# Transferring magento website to sub domain gives 404 error but works fine on main domain

Tags: 404-page, .htaccess

I have a magento (1.9.2.1) setup on a main domain ( www.mysite.com ) and now I want to transfer it from main domain to subdoamin like (sub.mysite.com).
Changed app/etc/local.xml file details
Cleared cache and session from var folder but no use except the home page nothing is working, gives 404 errors.
I'm using Godaddy Linux Hosting for it and check -
my .htaccess file for sub domain

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub.mysite.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L] 


RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ mysite.com

</IfModule>
```

I'm new to magento I've no knowledge about working with htaccess help me to get it done..

Answer (score 0):

You need also change in database table:**core_config_data**

For value of path: base unsecure url and base secure url

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not mentioning i changed secure and unsecure urls in **core_config_table** like

```
web/unsecure/base_url        http://www.sub.mysite.com/
web/secure/base_url         https://www.sub.mysite.com/
```